# watchdog daemon failes to start on reboot

Tags: linux, watchdog

I have installed watchdog on my embedded linux system.

#### Watchdog.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=watchdog daemon

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/watchdog
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '[ -z "${watchdog_module}" ] || [ "${watchdog_module}" = "none" ] || /sbin/modprobe $watchdog_module'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '[ x$run_watchdog != x1 ] || exec /usr/sbin/watchdog $watchdog_options'
PIDFile=/var/run/watchdog.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

then I executed

```
ln /lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service /etc/systemd/system/

systemctl enable watchdog.service
Synchronizing state of watchdog.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable watchdog
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/watchdog.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/watchdog.service → /etc/systemd/system/watchdog.service.
```

#### /etc/default/watchdog

```
# Start watchdog at boot time? 0 or 1
run_watchdog=1
watchdog_module="bcm2835-wdt"
watchdog_restart=1
```

#### watchdog.conf

```
root@raspberrypi-cm3:/etc# cat watchdog.conf
#ping                   = 172.31.14.1
#ping                   = 172.26.1.255
#interface              = eth0
file                    = /var/log/messages
max-load-1              = 24
# Note that this is the number of pages!
# To get the real size, check how large the pagesize is on your machine.
min-memory              = 1

watchdog-device = /dev/watchdog
watchdog-timeout        = 15

# This greatly decreases the chance that watchdog won't be scheduled before
# your machine is really loaded
realtime                = yes
priority                = 1
```

The watchdog does not work after reboot. There was bug reported regarding this. And the patch suggested was to add the install section.

```
[Unit]
Description=watchdog daemon
Conflicts=wd_keepalive.service
After=multi-user.target
OnFailure=wd_keepalive.service

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/watchdog
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '[ -z "${watchdog_module}" ] || [ "${watchdog_module}" = "none" ] || /sbin/modprobe $watchdog_module'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '[ $run_watchdog != 1 ] || exec /usr/sbin/watchdog $watchdog_options'
ExecStopPost=/bin/sh -c '[ $run_wd_keepalive != 1 ] || false'

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

But as you can see I already have the install section and I am still facing the same issue.
Any help will be appreciated